# How can I embed Youtube homepage to my website iframe or embed or object element?

Tags: javascript, html

In HTML ,
if I do this ->
`<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/"></iframe>`
or,
 `<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/"></embed>`
or,
 `<object data="https://www.youtube.com/"></embed>`

it shows me an error { `Refused to display 'https://www.youtube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.` }
and says youtube.com refused to connect.
can I get rid off?
Is there any way to show youtube **homepage** to my website  `iframe`  or  `embed`  or  `object`  element?

Answer (score 0):

You should always read the docs first:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

You cannot embed youtube.com directly in an iframe, because the setting `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` only allows embeddings on websites which run on the same domain (in this case youtube.com).

What you can do instead is embedding the YouTube player: https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Answer (score 0):

Good try, normally you can indeed add a site with iframe in your own site like:

```
<iframe src="https://yoursite.com/" " width="100% " height="600 "></iframe>
```

Websites like youtube can use [x-frame options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) or a [content security policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) to check if other website may embed them on their own page.

This is an important security feature to prevent [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking), which is an attack that allows malicious sites to trick users into clicking links on a site. [source](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/xframe-neterror-page?as=u&utm_source=inproduct)